# Plugin for pdf creation in codeigniter that support turkish character

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have used dom pdf class in codeigniter to create html to pdf creation. But this dom pdf doesn't support turkish character. Is there any pdf plugin that support turkish character.

Thanks
Shylaja

Comment: Your title says CodeIgniter but you've tagged the question with CakePHP. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: Codeigniter.I am asking about codeigniter

Comment: In that case do not tag your question CakePHP. I'm editing it for you.

Answer (score 3):

To support the Turkish language in DOMPDF, a Turkish character uses the dejavu font

```
.turkish
{
        font-family: 'dejavu sans';
}
```

download the font from below link

http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download

and copy to folder dompdf/lib/fonts

dom pdf support turkish character by using dejavu